# unable to send accessibility event in Android

Tags: android, android-snackbar, accessibility

I am trying to send a accessibility right after a snackbar is shown. But nothing gets played. here is my code which is in onStart() life cycle method:

```
            final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar
                       .make(findViewById(R.id.container), "snackbars are cool", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
               snackbar.setActionTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.snackbar_actions));


        View snackbarView = snackbar.getView();
   snackbarView.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
   TextView textView = (TextView) snackbarView.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
   textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
   snackbar.show();


//time to send a accessibility event below
       final ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.container);
       if (parentView != null) {
           final AccessibilityManager a11yManager =
                   (AccessibilityManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);

           if (a11yManager != null && a11yManager.isEnabled()) {
               final AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain();
               snackbarView.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(e);
               e.getText().add("some more text to say");
//nothing happens here

           parentView.requestSendAccessibilityEvent(snackbarView, e);
       }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

some developer wrote a fix for this.  My other issue was i should not call it in onStart for some reason. Anyway i created a utils method and used the developers commands which look like this:

```
if (!mA11yManager.isEnabled()) {
    return;
}

// Prior to SDK 16, announcements could only be made through FOCUSED
// events. Jelly Bean (SDK 16) added support for speaking text verbatim
// using the ANNOUNCEMENT event type.
final int eventType;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
    eventType = AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED;
} else {
    eventType = AccessibilityEventCompat.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT;
}

// Construct an accessibility event with the minimum recommended
// attributes. An event without a class name or package may be dropped.
final AccessibilityEvent event = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(eventType);
event.getText().add(text);
event.setEnabled(isEnabled());
event.setClassName(getClass().getName());
event.setPackageName(mContext.getPackageName());

// JellyBean MR1 requires a source view to set the window ID.
final AccessibilityRecordCompat record = new AccessibilityRecordCompat(event);
record.setSource(this);

// Sends the event directly through the accessibility manager. If your
// application only targets SDK 14+, you should just call
// getParent().requestSendAccessibilityEvent(this, event);
mA11yManager.sendAccessibilityEvent(event);}
```

you can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18502185/835883)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add more info to your accessibility event you could implement the `AccessibilityDelegate` for your view and override `onInitializeAccessibilityEvent`

```
@Override 
public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent event) {
  super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(event);
  event.getText().add("some more to say");
}
```

Comment: no because i wanted it to get fired right as soon as the snackbar is being shown it was not.